# Нужно сделать hover при любой точке со прикасания с div

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вообщем есть блок div, внутри есть ещё блок div который появляется при наведении на сам блок, есть так же текст, который должен появлятся при наведении(без наведения на любую часть блока, этого текста быть не должно), вообще большую часть я разобрался как сделать, не могу лишь понять как сделать что бы блок текста появлялся при наведении на любую точку блока а не только при наведении на текст или его границы.

```css
.prices {
  width: 100%;
  height: 880px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.item1 {
  width: 265px;
  height: 301px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 50px 0px 88px 390px;
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item1:hover {
  background-image: url(../img/bg_hover.jpg);
  opacity: 1;
}

.item1:hover img {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.prices_img1 {
  width: 260px;
  height: 199px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.makers {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 47px 0px 0 -215px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: italic;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  letter-spacing: 0.8px;
  opacity: 0;
}

div .makers:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.description_of_materials {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: -117px 0 0 0;
  border: 0px solid red;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 11.5px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: italic;
  padding: 0 16px 0 16px;
  line-height: 17px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 1;
}

.description_of_materials:hover {
  opacity: 0, 5;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.title_of_item1 {
  display: block;
  margin: 21px 0 0 39px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 1.1px;
}

.price_of_item1 {
  display: block;
  margin: 16px 0 0 65px;
  color: #e0182a;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 1.1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="prices">
  <span class="title_of_prices">Цены на <span class="red_word">кровельные материалы</span></span>
  <div class="item1">
    <div class="hover_item1"></div><img src="img/metalocherepica.jpg" class="prices_img1"><span class="makers">Производители</span><br><span class="description_of_materials">Металл: SSAB (Sweden), Thyssen Krupp (Germany), Arcelor Mittal (Germany, Poland), U.S.Steel (Slovakia), DONGBU (Korea, СТРУКТУРА ДЕРЕВА), Украина</span>
    <span
      class="title_of_item1">Металлочерепица</span><span class="price_of_item1">от 86,98 грн/м2</span></div>
  <div class="item2"><img src="img/profnastil.jpg"><span class="title_of_item2">Профнастил</span><span class="price_of_item2">от 56,98 грн/м2</span></div>
  <div class="item3"><img src="img/water_systems.jpg"><span class="title_of_item3">Водосточные системы</span><span class="price_of_item3">от 50 грн/м.п.</span></div>
  <div class="item4"><img src="img/heaters.jpg"><span class="title_of_item4">Утеплители</span><span class="price_of_item4">от 14,59 грн</span></div>
  <div class="item5"><img src="img/siding.jpg"><span class="title_of_item5">Cайдинг</span><span class="price_of_item5">от 159,98 грн/м2</span></div>
  <div class="item6"><img src="img/plenki.jpg"><span class="title_of_item6">Кровельные пленки</span><span class="price_of_item6">от 8,95 грн/м2</span></div>
  <div class="item7"><img src="img/pilo_mat.jpg"><span class="title_of_item7">Пиломатериалы</span><span class="price_of_item7">от 2090,59 грн/м3</span></div>
  <div class="item8"><img src="img/met_planki.jpg"><span class="title_of_item8">Металлические планки</span><span class="price_of_item8">от 8 грн/м.п.</span></div>
</div>
```

Выручите пожалуйста, не обязательно даже код переделывать просто можете подсказать какими свойствами это можно делать)

Comment: Ты хотя бы объясни внятно, на какой `div`  надо навести в любом месте, что бы что-то там всплыло...?

Comment: извиняюсь hover_item1, этот  блок)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно вас понял

```
.item1:hover .description_of_materials {
    opacity: 1;
}

.description_of_materials {
     opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое, помогло)

Comment: @АлександрПриступа если ответ помог, пожалуйста, отметьте его решением